# General C# question

Tags: c#, exception, language-design

Following class has two method wherein M1 complain ‘not all code path return a value’ and M2 doesn’t.

Question: How does the compiler resolve M2 in context of return value ? How NotImplementedException instance is implicitly casted as int (if there is any internal compile time resolution)

```
class A
        {
            int M1()
            {
            }
            int M2()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

Comment: <HIMYM>General Seesharp (salutes) </HIMYM>

Comment: I can't seem to find where in the C# specification this process is described, can anyone point that out?

Comment: @SWeko: Tracked it down. Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664437(VS.71).aspx (last paragraph).

Comment: @Jon, tnx. **"The endpoint of the method body of a value-returning method must not be reachable."** is basically the reason why M2 is ok, and M1 generates an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A method is not always required to return a value; in particular, it is also allowed to exit by throwing an exception (in which case no value is returned).

**Edit:** Specifically, [the rules for the body of a method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664437%28VS.71%29.aspx) that returns `int` are:

1. All `return` statements in the method must return an expression convertible to `int`
2. The end of the method block must not be reachable

In your example, the compiler can prove that `M2` always exits by throwing, so the end of the method block is not reachable (satisfies rule #2). There are also no `return` statements, which also satisfies rule #1. Hence this is a valid method definition.

On the other hand, `M1` does not satisfy rule #2 so it is not legal.

You are probably misled by the error message which does not mention throwing at all, but consider that in almost all cases methods with return values do `return` instead of throwing -- the compiler just tells you want you probably forgot to do.

Comment: aw to fast for my WP7 key pad.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions affect the flow of the code.  Any statements after the throw would not be executed, the compiler can prove this so is happy with the path through the method.

The exception would not result in an `int` being returned, nothing would be returned in the normal sense.  Instead an exception is generated, the CLR handles these differently.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The exception won't be cast as an int. The compiler knows that it is an exception that will always be reached so doesn't complain. When the exception is hit it will unwind the stack to an exception handling blocks or crash. An int will never be returned to the method caller.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ah5wsex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx),

> The throw statement is used to signal the occurrence of an anomalous situation (exception) during the program execution.

When code execution run into **throw** statement, program is stopped and an exception message is shown to an user (if a programmer didn't specify any error handling logic)